# Best practices for modifying collection inplace with LINQ

Tags: linq, collections, fluent-interface

I have a collection with objects of different types, each of them inheriting from a class named Component. I then want to modify the collections by my needs nicely, with use of kind of declarative and fluent syntax.

For each item type in the collection i need to do other actions so i came up with the following LINQ style extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DoWith<T, T2>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T2> action)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (item is T2 t)
            action(t);

        yield return item;
    }
}
```

So I call it like that:

```
myComponents
         .DoWith((ConstructionSiteComponent c) => c.structureTemplateKey = "newTemplate")
         .DoWith((EntityNameComponent c) => c.Name = $"Construction site for {origName}");
```

But surprise, nothing happens since the enumerable is not enumerated.
Sure I can fix this by either actually using a foreach statement of even calling .ToArray() which internally enumerates the collection, but this all does not feel right.

I would also imagine instead of modifying items to actually replace them, but i guess the problem would also apply then also, right?

Comment: There are no best practices. LINQ is immutable by default. What you are trying to do is multiple enumerations of single Enumerable, which is bad. `List` has `ForEach` method and it should be enough. Anyway, you can create extension method for `List` or other collection interface, returning the same instance and it will be ok,

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: Nothing is enumerated here, that was my point.. My DoWith method works like the Where clause, which also only "virtually" enumerates the collection. A Linq expression with multiple where clauses is also not enumerated multiple times.